# Fourier transform via residues

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Trying to compute the following expression by hand and mathematica, namely
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx \frac{x^2}{x^2+n^2}\frac{e^{ixk}}{x^2+a^2}$, where $a^2\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ gives me different results.

Clearly, it has four purely imaginary poles and I would construct $2$ half-circles eincirling either the $2$ with positive imaginary part (for $k>0$) or the $2$ with negative imaginary part (for $k<0$). Interestingly, mathematica gives different results if one feeds it with the above expression (FourierTransform vs. Integrate). How is this possible?

Edit:
The calculation per hand gives: 
$I=\frac{-\pi|n|e^{-|n||k|}}{-|n|^2+a^2}+\frac{\pi|a|e^{-|a||k|}}{-|n|^2+a^2}$

Comment: What is the result you obtained; what were Mathematica's?

Comment: Why do you write $dx$ before your integrand? This is the most atrocious notation I've ever seen.

Comment: @Regis : The notation is common in Physics because they view the integral as an operator to be applied on the left as one would with other linear operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to just use a little partial fractions and write 
$${x^2 \over (x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + n^2)} = -{a^2 \over n^2 - a^2}{1 \over x^2 + a^2}
+ {n^2 \over n^2 - a^2}{1 \over x^2 + n^2}$$
So you need to find
$$-{a^2 \over n^2 - a^2}\int_{\mathbb R} {e^{ikx} \over x^2 + a^2} + {n^2 \over n^2 - a^2}\int_{\mathbb R} {e^{ikx} \over x^2 + n^2}$$
A simple application of residues in the upper half plane then gives for $k \geq 0$ that this is equal to
$$-{a^2 \over n^2 - a^2}{\pi e^{-|a|k} \over |a|} + {n^2 \over n^2 - a^2}{\pi e^{-|n|k} \over |n|}$$
$$=-{\pi|a|\over n^2 - a^2} e^{-|a|k} + {\pi |n| \over n^2 - a^2}e^{-|n|k}$$
If $k < 0$ we get the same result as for $|k| > 0$ since it just changes the imaginary part of the integral which is $0$. So for any $k$ the integral is 
$$=-{\pi|a|\over n^2 - a^2} e^{-|ak|} + {\pi |n| \over n^2 - a^2}e^{-|nk|}$$
This agrees with what you got.

Comment: Hi @Zarrax and thanks for this but the partial fraction does not equal the lhs.

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected it and now it agrees with what you got.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that the problems with mathematica were related to either writing the FourierTransform, Integrate or FourierCosTransform commands.